# Subsetting and Altering Only Certain Elements of a Vector in R

Tags: r, subset

I am student who is working with the iris dataset in r. This has 3 flower types.

I am supposed to create a new vector of the Petal.Length vector in one statement that is the same but for only the Virginica Species I take the log base 10 value.  I am not sure how to command r to take the log base 10 value of only the virginica values in the Petal.Length column but to keep the other values for the other two flowers the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets in `R` to subset data. The generic formula is `object[object operator condition]`. For example, `iris$Petal.Length[iris$Species == "virginica"]` is equivalent to saying "Show me the `Petal.Length` values only for the `Species` values that equal "virginica".

Comment: It would be good if you @Nasa write the current code you have written. Alternatively, give us sample input and sample output if you need a code to be given as an answer.